# Div's are moving when zoom in-out

Tags: html, css

I have the next code:
[JsFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qgnsuck/4/)

But when I zoom in and zoom out the div's are moving 1 or 2px on the screen, but what I expect is that it must be fixed in its position.

For example, the left one (.hora) with 12:07 gets out of the orange border, the center div with letters is also moving its top-bottom position...

```
<div class="interiorPantalla">
  <div class="interiorSuperior">   
    <div class="hora line-left">
      <span>12:07</span>
    </div>
    <div class="proxSortidaCCA">
      <span class="superiorPantallaCatala">Pròximes sortides</span><br>
      <span class="superiorPantallaCastella">Próximas salidas</span>
      <span class="superiorPantallaAngles notbold">Next departures</span>
    </div>
    <div class="logoPantalla1" >
      <img src="images/123.png" class="logoPantalla" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible. Create an example with minimal code that reproduces the problem your facing and edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some testing and I realized that the `span` inside `.hora`, by having a big font-size, and being an inline element, is growing out of it's box due to line-height.

As soon as you turn it into a block element with `display:block`, it goes back inside the box and you can remove your positioning adjustments.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me with .hora, but no with .proxSortidaCCA and its children. Any idea?

Comment: @Jordi45454, the principle is the same. Elements like `span` are inline by default, and inline elements' heights are affected by their line-heights.
If you turn them into block elements, you will have control over their heights, paddings, etc., and you will be able to solve the problem.
This gets even clearer to see as when you zoom the page, the font-size changes, thus affecting the line-height and making the discrepancies more pronounced